# org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: @Autowired not working in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am currently working on a Spring Boot application, and `@Autowired` does not work for my main classes, only the test classes. I have already tried other solutions, but nothing has been working for me so far.

The errors I get are

`org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.johndoe.handler.MyHandler' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`

and

`org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.johndoe.repos.MyDataRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`.

My current project structure can be abstracted to this:

```
MyProject
|- Some other folders and files
|- MyApplicationFolder
   |- build.gradle
   |- bin
   |- build
   |- src
      |- main
         |- java
            |- com
               |- johndoe
                  |- repos
                     |- MyDataRepository.java
                  |- data
                     |- MyData.java
                  |- myapp
                     |- MyApplication.java
                  |- handler
                     |- MyHandler.java
                  |- request
                     |- MyRequest.java
         |- resources
      |- test
```

In MyApplication.java:

```
package com.johndoe.myapp;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.johndoe", "com.johndoe.repos", "com.johndoe.data", "com.johndoe.myapp", "com.johndoe.handler", "com.johndoe.request"})
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.johndoe.repos")
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

In MyData.java:

```
package com.johndoe.data;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_table")
public class MyData {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private String id;

    // More data members
}
```

In MyDataRepository.java:

```
package com.johndoe.repos;

import com.johndoe.data.MyData;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import java.util.*;

@Repository
public interface MyDataRepository extends CrudRepository<Tour, Long> {
    List<MyData> findAll();

    // More functions
}
```

In MyRequest.java:

```
package com.johndoe.request;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyRequest {
    // More code
}
```

In MyHandler.java:

```
package com.johndoe.handler;

import com.johndoe.request.MyRequest;
import com.johndoe.data.MyData;
import com.johndoe.repos.MyDataRepository;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyHandler {
    @Autowired
    private MyDataRepository repo;
    @Autowired
    private MyRequest req;

    // More code
}
```

In build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

dependencies {
    compile project(':<other folder in MyProject>')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.5.6.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") 
    compile("org.hsqldb:hsqldb:2.3.0")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure")
}
```

Building this will result in the aforementioned errors and I am not sure why. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Remove `scanBasePackages` attribute from `@SpringBootApplication` and see what will happen.

Comment: Remove `@Repository` from your `MyDataRepository`

Comment: @Antoniossss I tried your suggestion, but I still get the same error.

Comment: @FelipeMariano Still getting the same error. :(

Comment: how do you run the app?

Comment: @Antoniossss I just run `./gradlew build` on CLI in the root directory. If I comment out all the `@Autowired` and repositories, and instantiate the objects with `new`, then I do not get an error. All the objects that are annotated with `@Autowired ` in my test classes also work fine regardless.

Comment: So for some reasons scanning does not work

Comment: @Antoniossss That's what I suspect.

Comment: Let just the scan on com.johndoe or remove it and let the others. Maybe multiple scan can create bean ambiguity but it's just an hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move `MyApplication` from `com.johndoe.myapp` to `com.johndoe`
Your MyApplication class should look like:

```
package com.johndoe;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Make sure that you do not have other classes with annotation `@SpringBootApplication` in your dependencies:

```
compile project(':<other folder in MyProject>')
```

Spring boot can find this class and use it for the scan (`@SpringBootApplication` annotation contains `@ComponentScan`. The default behavior of `@ComponentScan` is to look for classes within the same package and all sub-packages of the annotated class)

Comment: As I understand `scanBasePackages` in `@SpringBootApplication` is not enough. You should also add:
`@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.johndoe.data"})`
But the easy fix is to move `MyApplication`

Comment: `@EntityScan` reffers to domain classes (those annotated with `@Entitiy`) not Spring components.

Comment: It requires for creating `MyDataRepository`.

Comment: Will try this now!

Comment: @SergeyBezvershenko `MyApplication` is now in `com.johndoe`, and its annotations are as follows:

`@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages= {"com.johndoe"})`
`@EntityScan("com.johndoe.data")`
`@EnableJpaRepositories("com.johndoe.repositories")`

But I still get the same error. :(

I run my app with `./gradlew build`, if that is of any significance.

Comment: @SergeyBezvershenko Weirdly enough, if I put `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.johndoe.request"}` as an annotation for `MyHandler`, it injects `MyRequest`.

Comment: Changed answer. Maybe you have another class with annotation @SpringBootApplication in your dependencies

Comment: @MiG98789 You dont have to have `@ComponentScan` as it is included in `@SpringBootApplication` In general, from what you have shown, it should work. Either you have a typo somewhere as you are keep using `scanBasePackages` or its is environemental/configuration issue